# HomeController inherit from BaseController, but didn't run a function in BaseController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization

I create clean APS.NET MVC 4 project and I try make internationalization using [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx) tutorial.

I have problem with using baseController, because when I run project, function from base controller isn't execute. Maybe I forget implement something...

BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
            string cultureName = null;
            //Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
            HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
            if (cultureCookie != null)
                cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
            else
                cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; //obtain it from HTTP

            //Validation culture name
            cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

            //Modify current thread's cultures
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            base.ExecuteCore();
        }

    }
```

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to override the `Initialize` method instead `ExecuteCore`.

Here is an explanation and a solution: [ExecuteCore() in base class not fired in MVC 4 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555069/executecore-in-base-class-not-fired-in-mvc-4-beta)